# Make some audio effects and store it in a mediaplayer

Tags: android, echo, android-mediaplayer, effects, soundpool

I need make some audio effects on a list of recordings in .3gp format that was stored into device.

The audio effects that I need are the addition of reverberant sounds or the mixing with another audio files with sounds of traffic or a crowd.

I believe the best way to mix the audio recordings and the audio effects is with the SoundPool class. To make the SoundPool I followed the next tutorial: [Getting your feet wet in Android’s SoundPool](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/339/sinttulohh.jpg/)

For the echo effect I'm trying to use the audiofx package with the classes PresetReverb and EnvironmentalReverb but didn't makes the effect with my code:

```
public void playSoundPresetReverb(){

       PresetReverb pReverb  = new PresetReverb(1, 0);
       mp.attachAuxEffect(pReverb.getId());
       pReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
       pReverb.setEnabled(true);

       mp.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);


    }

public void playSoundEnvironmentReverb(){

       eReverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(0, 0);
       eReverb.setDecayHFRatio((short) 1000);
       eReverb.setDecayTime(1000);
       eReverb.setDensity((short) 1000);
       eReverb.setDiffusion((short) 1000);
       eReverb.setReverbLevel((short) -1000);
       eReverb.setReverbDelay((short) 50);
       eReverb.setEnabled(true);
       //mp.attachAuxEffect(eReverb.getId());
       mp.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);


    }
```

But the playing sound with reverb is without effect. I think the effect is applied after before mp.start(); but I don't know if is needed some preparative for the MediaPlayer.

This is the LogCat for the activity:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/339/sinttulohh.jpg/

My last question is how to save the mediaplayer after the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the new object (reverb) with your media player session.

You can do it this way:

```
eReverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(0, mp.getsessionid());
```

// mp is your audio player object

Greeetz!

Comment: Hello, I am facing same problem did you got any solution for this. I am looking for solution for so many days but not got any. Please share your solution to reverb problem thanks in advance and eagerly waiting for your response ......